# Binding EditText text to a variable?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I am trying to bind the text of `EditText` object to a local for the view variable, but probably I do not understand how.

- How could bind `EditText` object with a variable in `Java` - `Android 4.0.3` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind EditText to the local variable of type EditText

```
EditText text=new EditText(this);

text=youredittex;
```

Comment: Hello. Could I bind it to a string ?

Comment: @MiloshSilk ok I'll ask you simple thing, is it possible to lift a hill with your finger...How could you ask that....You can't even store List obect in a string how could you ask this..?

Comment: Probably he were asking about the text property, not the object itself.

Comment: Wow. That was fast.. Thank You. Yes. I wish to know if there is a way to bing it's property text to a string variable as well, or it is better to ask it in separate question ?

Comment: String edittextvalue=youredittext.getText().toString() ? is that something you want..?

Comment: Yes. But is it binded just this way ?

Comment: @MiloshSilk it will store the text entered in edittext to your string variable...

Comment: but when I change the variable value - will it change the text of EditText object ?

Comment: @Milosh Silk ..No it won't... You need to set text for EditText when the string changes

Comment: @Pragnani, I feel you didn't understand what MiloshSilk meant by binding. What you are talking about is "setting" the value of a text, "binding" is different. Binding is when you link a variable and a control together so that when the control's change, the variable will also, and when the variable change, the control will change. This is really helpful in saving you the time of having to add handlers, etc.

Comment: If you are into web development, AngularJS is a good example of binding. Have a look at this: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/databinding

Answer (score 7):

Make an variableChangedListener [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157123/in-android-how-do-i-take-an-action-whenever-a-variable-changes)

In the listener, add `setText(variable)` for the EditText

Comment: o! .. I didn't tough it is so complicated in Java. Thank You :)

Answer (score -1):

You can do by this:

```
EditText bindText=new EditText(context);

bindText=anyThingHere;
```