# Create boolean listener

Tags: android, boolean, listener

[In Android, how do I take an action whenever a variable changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157123/in-android-how-do-i-take-an-action-whenever-a-variable-changes/7157281#7157281)

So I want to implement a listener for an object I created. What I want it to do is execute a block of code when its value changes from false to true.

As I am following this thread, I can't understand where the person wants us to implement the last block of code containing the logic for the listener.

Could someone, hopefully, guide me in the right direction?

(This question is being asked here as I don't have enough rep. points)

Comment: Thanks for asking this question LT, helped me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That last bit of example code triggers the listener, so it basically needs to be run whenever the "event" occurs. In this case the "event" is whenever (wherever in the code) the value of the variable changes.

If you have a setter and that is the only place the value changes, that is where you'd put it. If you are changing the value in multiple places throughout your code, I would make a new private method (call it `signalChanged`), put your code there, and then call it immediately after the variable assignment in the cases you want the listener to fire.

Here's an example (some code borrowed from linked answer, haven't checked that it compiles).

```
public class MyObj
{        
    public MyObj(int value)
    {
        setValue(value);
    }

    private int myValue;
    public int getValue() { return myValue; }
    public void setValue( int value )
    {
        if (value != myValue)
        {
            myValue = value;
            signalChanged();
        }
    }

    public interface VariableChangeListener
    {
        public void onVariableChanged(Object... variableThatHasChanged);
    }

    private VariableChangeListener variableChangeListener;
    public void setVariableChangeListener(VariableChangeListener variableChangeListener)
    {
        this.variableChangeListener = variableChangeListener;
    }

    private void signalChanged()
    {
        if (variableChangeListener != null)
            variableChangeListener.onVariableChanged(myValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you :). This helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a callback interface 
here is a good about custom listener   [tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Creating-Custom-Listeners)

here is a sample

```
public class MyObj {
    VariableChanger onVariableChanged ;

    public void setOnVariableChanged(VariableChanger onVariableChanged) {
        this.onVariableChanged = onVariableChanged;
    }
     void log(){
        boolean changed = false;
        onVariableChanged.onVariableChanged();
        //this will call it 
    }

    interface VariableChanger{
       void onVariableChanged();
    }
}
class logic {
    MyObj mo = new MyObj();

    void main(){
        mo.setOnVariableChanged(new MyObj.VariableChanger() {

            @Override
            public void onVariableChanged() {
              //do your action
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

In Android, like any language, most developper uses logic comparisons to check values (if, else, switch, =, !=, >, <, etc) or Event (signal)

What kind of listener do you want to implement?

Comment: When you have enough reputation, please add this as a comment instead of an answer, as an answer which has the content of a comment is not useful to anyone.

Comment: That is why I posted it as a question.