# Is there an Android Listener for toggling View attribute boolean values on a list?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I wanted to know if there are any listeners in Android that allows you to toggle the common boolean-based attribute of a bunch/list of views (a set of TextViews etc. and attributes like say visibility or focusable), if one of them is changed. For example, if I have Views A, B and C and I only need one of them to be visible at a time based on one of them clicked. I can do this switch case below provided I've created OnClickListeners for each items A, B and C which works but this is long and tedious. Is there a better implementation than the one below?:

```
switch(v.getId()){
     Case R.id.A:
        //set A visible
        //set B invisible 
        //set C invisible 
        break;
     Case R.id.B:
        //set A invisible 
        //set B visible 
        //set C invisible 
        break;
     Case R.id.C:
        //set A invisible 
        //set B invisible 
        //set C visible
        break;
     default:
        //do something else
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is answered here. This is what I used when I needed to listen for a Boolean value that has been changed https://stackoverflow.com/a/7157281/2258389

Comment: I understand that I have to use a listeners for the boolean values I want changed. But that's not my problem. What I want is for the listener to detect any boolean value change from a list and set all the other boolean values from items of the same list to the opposite boolean value of the chesen changed value. So if one change to visibility of one item/view A is set to true, then all other itema/views (B and C) are set to false. If B however is turned to true, (A and C) will turn false.

Comment: you will have to set condition for that, if A == true, set A and C "false"

Comment: That's no different from the switch case sample I did above which achieves the same goal with the same amount of tedious effort of doing that for all n number of options + setting the other n-1 cases to the opposite boolean value n times. If I had 50+ cases, all with the same attribute that takes boolean values, it wouldn't be the best way to handle it.